# Set breakpoint in electron via chrome remote debugging API

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, electron, javascript-debugger, node-debugger

I'm building an open source Node.js debugger that is an electron app and uses the built in debugger in the render process. 
Full source: https://github.com/fijiwebdesign/electron-scope/

In the main process I want to launch the script to debug and set a breakpoint on the first line.

I'm following the tests in Electron for chrome debugger api: 
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/702352804239f58e5abcd0b96dbd748b68ab0278/spec/api-debugger-spec.js#L77

My code:

```
win.webContents.debugger.sendCommand(
        'Debugger.setBreakpointByUrl', {
            lineNumber: 0,
            url: './test.js'
        },
        function (err, result){
            if(err){
                console.error('Error:', err)
            }
            console.log('Breakpoint Result: ', result)
        })
```

Full ref: https://github.com/fijiwebdesign/electron-scope/blob/setBreakpoint/index.js#L51

This logs: `Result:  { breakpointId: './test.js:0:0', locations: [] }`

However, no breakpoint is set. I'm assuming if there were then locations would hold the information.

You can find the branch where I'm trying to set a breakpoint here: 
https://github.com/fijiwebdesign/electron-scope/tree/setBreakpoint

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to run `Debugger.enable` to activate the debugger so that subsequent debugger commands work. However, I'm not familiar with Electron's API, so it's possible that it inherently does.

```
win.debugger.sendCommand('Debugger.enable', {}, function() {
    setBreakpoint(win);
});
```